# How to upgrade a SQL Server 2012 .mdf file to SQL Server 2014?

Tags: sql-server, database

How can I use my database file (`.mdf`) created using SQL Server in 2012 in calling it from Visual Studio (as an instance)?

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source = .\\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog = DB; Integrated Security = False; User ID = hi; Password=123");
```

That is the code to call it but only for SQL Server 2012. How to use it in SQL Server 2014? I kept on getting this error:

> This database file is not compatible with the current instance of SQL
>   Server.
>
> To resolve this issue, you must upgrade the database file by creating
>   a new data connection, or you must modify the existing connection to
>   this database file.

Comment: Databases aren't *files*. You can't just take an `mdf` file from one server and open it on another. Detach the database from the older server and attach it to the new one. Detaching ensures that any existing transactions are completed before the database is taken offline. Attach takes care of any necessary upgrade steps.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I already did I placed it in my sql server managament 2014 and it read it, now my only problem is how will i call it in visual studio? What is the proper instance for it?

Comment: In your sql server 2014 instance, run the following script: `CREATE DATABASE DB ON
(FILENAME = 'PATH_TO_YOUR_MDF_FILE' )
FOR ATTACH`

Comment: @Hackerman sir can you post it as an answer? I can't seem to grasp on how to do it.

Comment: @MichaelZ If the database appears in SSMS, it's already copied and working. To connect, you use the *same* server, instance names and credentials that you use in SSMS. Instead of hand-coding the connection string, add a Connection String setting in your application's settings and use its dialog box to connect to the database. That will create the connection string for you and save it in app.config

Answer (score 1):

Late the party, but I found this out. 
The upgrade isn't automatic. The key is to trigger it. Go to

```
 `Data Connections -> Default Connection -> Right Click -> Modify connection -> Advanced -> Data Source`
```

Then there should be a pre-populated dropdown containing your instance.

```
ok -> ok
```

Then you'll get this screen. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kgR1W.png)

```
Default Connection Right Click -> refresh
```

Your db is [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZR10E.png)
Your mdf is upgraded.